# Creating an instance of each class when choosing it's tab (JTabbedPane)

Tags: java, swing, io, jtabbedpane

Project Screenshot

[image]

I have multiple tabs, each tab refers to a class, what I need is to create an instance of the class when the specific tab is pressed.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to read only when the group tab is opened and  detect when the selected tab changes you need add ChangeListener and get its index:

```
getJTabbedPane().addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
        switch (tabPane.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
            //do something
                break;
            case 1:
            //do something
                 break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    });
```

Instead of index you can use also selected component if your group tab implemented as custom class:

```
 getJTabbedPane().getSelectedComponent() instanceof <CustomPanel.class>
```

Comment: please check this question[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011931/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-an-arraylist-from-a-class-in-a-different-class-same]

Comment: i need to use the arraylist read in the change listener of the main class and use it in the class group netbeans is forcing me to make it static but this is making me problems